# Encountered Invalid redirect. Missing location header. Unity issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, server

I am using Unity WWWForm to post licence validation request to a URL.
The code is working in Unity 5.6, but it is not working in Unity 2017.3.1f1. I also tried this in Unity 2018. It didn't work.

This is the error message:
Encountered invalid redirect (missing Location header?)

This is the code I am using.

```
void Awake() {
    Instance = this;
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
    mainHeader = form.headers;

    mainHeader ["Authorization"] = "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes ("dummyId:#dummyPassword"));

}


public void HitForLicence(){
    string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson (new LicenseData { 

        LICENCE_KEY="kwsnfdksfksnf",
        MACHINE_IP="192.168.1.1"

    });




    Debug.Log (jsonData);

    byte[ ] postData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (jsonData);


    //headers ["Authorization"] = "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes ("unity:@piun!ty"));
    if (mainHeader.ContainsKey ("Content-Type")) {

        mainHeader ["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

    } else {

        mainHeader.Add ("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }


    WWW www = new WWW (LicenseURL, postData, mainHeader);
    StartCoroutine (CheckForLicense (www));

}

public IEnumerator CheckForLicense (WWW www)
{

    Debug.Log("Check For License..");


    yield return www;


    //if (www.isDone ) {
        if (www.error != null) {
            ClearKeyBox ();
            print (www.error);
        }
        else {
            print (www.text);
            jsonNode = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(www.text);
            print ("MSG "+ jsonNode["MSG"].ToString());
        }
    //} 


    if (jsonNode != null && jsonNode["MSG"].Equals(ValidStr)) {
        HandleTextFile.WriteString(_SystemMACAddress+"-"+keyEntered);
        // Next screen
    } else {
        ClearKeyBox ();
    }

}
```

Anyone faced this before? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally solved my problem.

```
public void Post(string url)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate,
                 X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    { 
        return true; 
    };


    string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson (new LicenseData { 

        LICENCE_KEY="kwsnfdksfksnf",
        MACHINE_IP="192.168.1.1"

    });


    Debug.Log (jsonData);

    byte[ ] postData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (jsonData);



    if (mainHeader.ContainsKey ("Content-Type")) {

        mainHeader ["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

    } else {

        mainHeader.Add ("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }
    StartCoroutine (HttpRequest(postData, url));
}





IEnumerator HttpRequest(byte[] postData, string url)
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(new LicenseData
            {
                LICENCE_KEY = "kwsnfdksfksnf",
                MACHINE_IP = "192.168.1.1"
            });

        streamWriter.Write(jsonData);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        print(result);
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with `WWW` under Unity 2018, too.

Currently I am using [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) - I think `WWW` is obsolete, but I can not find any reference to this.

Basically change your code like this:

```
...

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(LicenseURL, form)
    StartCoroutine (CheckForLicense (www));

}

public IEnumerator CheckForLicense (WWW www)
{

    Debug.Log("Check For License..");

...
```

I think you have to set the head via [`SetRequestHeader`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader.html) and put your post data into the WWWForm...

I am not able to check it right now... Hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Like dome12b said, change to UnityWebRequest.

Additionaly however, set chunked transfer to false. I had the same problem and it was driving me nuts. Chunked transfer fixed it all.

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(LicenseURL, form)
www.chunkedTransfer = false;
```